# Custom ACTION as fixture member - google test

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I want to execute an action every time a mock function is called. I tried implementing this using ACTION_P. See the code below:

```
ACTION_P(CompleteRegistrationWithStatus, status)
{
    arg1->registrationCompleted(status);
}
```

And the expectation goes like:

```
 EXPECT_CALL(*mockObj, register(_)).WillOnce(CompleteRegistrationWithStatus(success));
```

Problem is, I had to use the same expectation multiple times, just different *status*. So I needed to put the expectation inside a member function of the test fixture to avoid code redundancy. But the function cannot access the ACTION_P I defined since it is not a member of the fixture.

I tried searching for ACTIONs that are fixture members, like that of MATCHERs, but to no avail.

Any suggestions for a possible solution or alternative? Any form of help is much appreciated. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand the need to put the expectation in a member function of the fixture, but you should be able to get the behavior you want using InSequence:

```
{
    InSequence s;
    EXPECT_CALL(*mockObj, register(_))
        .WillOnce(CompleteRegistrationWithStatus(success));
    EXPECT_CALL(*mockObj, register(_))
        .WillOnce(CompleteRegistrationWithStatus(failure));
}
```